# Adding hyperlink to a csv using python

Tags: python, csv, arcgis

I am trying to add a hyperlinks to a csv. I exported data and attachments from ArcGIS Survey123. The csv only has the file name of the photos,

`photos_20220216144827.jpg, photos_20220329110509.jpg, 60th_virtual_background.jpg`

I would like to add a hyperlink for faster access to the images. All photos are saved in the following directory `B:\Survey123\survey_attachments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with this line of code.

```
# Adding hyperlink
df = pd.read_excel(surveyResults)
df['Column containing image name'] = '=HYPERLINK("location of folder containing images' + df["Column containing image name"] + '")'
df.to_excel('location where to save new excel', index=False)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).